# SetInterval timer on multiple objects cancels after initializing

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, setinterval

I have multiple objects displayed in my document that have states (statuses) on them. If an object's state is set to `active`, I display a count up timer to show users how long the object has been active for. Hence the code:

```
  countTimer = (el, seconds) ->
    setInterval (->
      totalSeconds = seconds
      ++totalSeconds
      hour    = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600)
      minute  = Math.floor((totalSeconds - (hour * 3600)) / 60)
      seconds = totalSeconds - (hour * 3600 + minute * 60)
      $(el).siblings('.status').find('.timer').text("#{hour}:#{minute}:#{seconds}")
    ), 1000

  $('.object').each (index, element) =>
    $el = $(element)
    secondsPassed = parseInt $el.data('start-time')
    if $el.data('state') == 'active'
      countTimer(element, secondsPassed)
```

On initialize, the script loads the correct time passed (based on `data-start-time`), e.g.

```
0:1:46
```

but then on the first second the timer of each element cancels out:

```
0:0:46
```

and then counts seconds only.

Not sure why that's happening. Any advice appreciated.

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/fsob9qfb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without using variables Variables change as each call function

Comment: could you elaborate please

Comment: This problem scope problem because setInterval scope is global scope and each function overrited global variables. You are welcome :)